# Using AR findAll function giving only one object back when using the with statement

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am having an issue with my Yii install where I am trying to get a fairly basic query back but I am not getting the results back that the online tutorials are saying that I should get. I have 2 models that look roughly like this:

Pricing:

```
class Pricing extends CActiveRecord
{
/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Pricing the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'pricing';
}

/**
* @return string the primary key
*/
public function primaryKey(){
    return 'ID';
}

...

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'xpricing_routes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PricingRoutes', 'ID_pricing'),
    );
}
```

and PricingRoutes:

```
class PricingRoutes extends CActiveRecord
{
/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return PricingRoutes the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'pricing_routes';
}

/**
* @return string the primary key
*/
public function primaryKey(){
    return 'ID';
}
...
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'xpricing' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Pricing', 'ID_pricing'),
    );
}
```

Then in the controller we have:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('xpricing_routes'); 
$criteria->together=true;       

$pricing_records = Pricing::model()->findAll($criteria);
$pricing_records_arr = CHtml::listData($pricing_records, 'id', 'name');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($pricing_records);
print_r($pricing_record_arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

As you probably already know, we have 2 tables called pricing and pricing_routes. The pricing routes table has a foreign key called ID_pricing that goes to the ID field in the pricing table. The pricing table has one entry and the pricing_routes table has 4 entries that all have the primary key for the one item in the pricing table in the ID_pricing field. So we should be getting 4 results to the query that we are running and when I run the query that Yii is generating with AR, that is what I get.

The problem that we are having is that the $pricing_records variable is an array that only has one Pricing object. That object contains the data we need but not really in a usable fashion. The $pricing_records_arr variable is just an empty array. The documentation that I have found seems to suggest that we should be getting an array of pricing objects each containing the information from the pricing_routes table as well. We are aware that using AR may not be the best way to get this data but we have our reasons for getting this to work so any ideas on how to do that would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

It turns out that this ended up being a misunderstanding of what I was getting back. The comments on this question gave me the information that I needed.

Comment: try without a criteria like `Pricing::model()->with('xpricing_routes')->findAll();`

Comment: Thank you for the response but we actually tried that already and got the same result.

Comment: Then you have to findout what exactly the sql quries are done in the background. `CProfileLogRoute` may help you

Comment: No No. Thats not the exact problem. you must change the line to `$pricing_records_arr = CHtml::listData($pricing_records->xpricing_routes, 'id', 'name');` to get 4 values in the array

Comment: Yeah, I did that and when I ran that query directly on the database, it came back with the results that it should with 4 rows.

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to Yii but how would I change that line to get the 4 values?

Comment: the variable `$pricing_records` is an array of variable containing 1 `Pricing` model. To get the related 4 `PricingRoutes` you must use `$pricing_records->xpricing_routes` which is an arry of 4 `PricingRoutes` model. So In your `CHtml::listData` you shoud use `$pricing_records->xpricing_routes`

Comment: Ok, I changed that line to $pricing_records_arr = CHtml::listData($pricing_records[0]->xpricing_routes, 'id', 'name'); and I still got an empty array.

Comment: then post the output of `CVarDumper::dump($pricing_records)'` and `CVarDumper::dump($pricing_records[0]->xpricing_routes)`

Comment: Ok, those dumps were too big for me to put here but I put them on a page at [link](http://caswellwebcreations.com/dump/vardump.html)

Comment: There is no `name` attribute in `PricingRoutes`. so `name` in `$pricing_records_arr = CHtml::listData($pricing_records[0]->xpricing_routes, 'id', 'name');` doesnt make any sense. replace it by `$pricing_records_arr = CHtml::listData($pricing_records[0]->xpricing_routes, 'ID', 'seg1_origin');` and do a `print_r($pricing_records_arr)`

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't make myself clear on my question. What I need is a way to iterate through the results that I am getting from the query that is being run. Making the change above only gave me one result of one field.

Comment: `foreach($pricing_records as $record)
{
  print_r($record->attributes);
  foreach($record->xpricing_routes as $route)
   print_r($route->attributes);
}`

Comment: That answered my question. I didn't realize that I had to look at the attributes to get the data that I wanted. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @dInGd0nG please expand/merge your comments into an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
$pricing_records = Pricing::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

you'll get only one active record with properties filled with the values from your table "pricing".
If you want to get all the records from "pricing_routes" belonging to this specific "pricing" you have to call

```
$pricing_records->xpricing_routes
```

where "xpricing_routes" is the name of the relationship you have correctly defined in your model. It returns array of PricingRoutes or null if there is no matching record.

Answer (score 0):

if you use findall it will return an array even there is one record

```
$pricing_records = Pricing::model()->findAll($criteria);
foreach($pricing_records as $var){
$var->xpricing_routes->ID_pricing;//any variable
}
```

or 
if there only one field you can use

```
$pricing_records = Pricing::model()->find($criteria);
$pricing_records->xpricing_routes->ID_pricing;//any variable
```